# Why does this json file have header?

Tags: json

[image]

This is what I use notepad ++ to open the look after.

It has a string of characters at the beginning,this is not like json format.

Do you think it is encrypted?Or a coding format?

Complete file in Google Drive.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6YqtvO7v-V3MWJQZTFQT25ScHM

Comment: Where'd you get it from? Did you ask whoever created it?

Comment: In Notepad++ select change to UTF-8 encoding or another type

Comment: Notepad ++ all types have been tried

Comment: Is this real json file?